# how to post select option value into jQuery ajax with name

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send section option value with ajax but only selection
and checkbox
the problem is that section and checkbox post undifined
thanx advanced

**php code**

```
<?php

    $paramateres = new ParametresApp();
    $paramateres->getparametres();
    $max_pages_nbr = $paramateres->max_pages_nbr;
    $idle_deconnexion = $paramateres->idle_deconnexion;
    $show_chat = $paramateres->show_chat;

?>
```

**html code**

```
    <form id="formparametres" class="form-row row shadow bg-white border row p-5 "
              method="post">

          <div class="form-check col-3 col-lg-3 ">

                <input name="show_chat" id="show_chat" type="checkbox"
                       class="form-check-input" value="<?php echo $show_chat; ?>"
                    <?php if ($show_chat == 1) {
                        echo 'checked="true" ';
                    }
                    ?>

                <label class="form-check-label"
                         for="show_chat"> Autoriser messenger </label>
                </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-lg-3">
                          <label class="form-control-label">idle deconexion</label>
                          <input name="idle_deconnexion" class="form-control"
                                 value="<?php echo $idle_deconnexion; ?>" required>
                    </div>

         <div class="input-wrapper col-4 col-lg-4">
                    <label class="form-control-label">max_pages_nbr</label>
                    <select name="max_pages_nbr" class="form-control" required>
                      <?php  echo '<option value="'.$max_pages_nbr.'">'.$max_pages_nbr.'</option>
                          <option value="5">5</option>
                          <option value="10">10</option>
                          <option value="15">15</option>
                          <option value="20">20</option>
                          <option value="25">25</option>';?>
                    </select>
              </div>
        </form>
```

**jquery code**

```js
      $("form").submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formData =
                     'show_chat=' + $('input[name=show_chat]').val() +                    
                        '&idle_deconnexion=' + $('input[name=idle_deconnexion]').val() +

                        '&max_pages_nbr=' + $('section[name=max_pages_nbr]').val() ;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "src/admins/inc/save_parametres.inc.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: formData, // serializes the form's elements.
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: Take a look here you have the same error with your data syntax : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007250/why-is-my-ajax-on-my-php-form-not-working/52007302

Comment: the data syntax is not **=** but **:** and don't add the **&**

Comment: Check the [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) you use and update your question.

Comment: Inazo its work with 5 input  componant in authers page thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formData = {'show_chat' : $('input[name=show_chat]').val(), 'idle_deconnexion' : $('input[name=idle_deconnexion]').val(), 'max_pages_nbr' : $('section[name=max_pages_nbr]').val() };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "src/admins/inc/save_parametres.inc.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: formData, // serializes the form's elements.
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }

                    });
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i have solveur thanx for all

**jquery**

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("value") == 1) {
                    $(this).attr("value", 0)
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("value", 1)
                }
            });
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formData =

                    'show_chat=' + $('#show_chat').attr("value") +
                    '&idle_deconnexion=' + $('input[name=idle_deconnexion]').val() +
                    '&max_pages_nbr=' + $('#max_pages_nbr option:selected').text() ;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "src/admins/inc/save_parametres.inc.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: formData, // serializes the form's elements.
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }

                });
});
});
```

***in may page src/admins/inc/save_parametres.inc.php***

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)){
    $show_chat= $_POST['show_chat'];
    $idle_deconnexion= $_POST['idle_deconnexion'];
    $max_pages_nbr= $_POST['max_pages_nbr'];


 $sql = "   update dms_parametres set parm_value=".$show_chat ." where  parm_name='show_chat';
            update dms_parametres set parm_value='" . $idle_deconnexion . "' where  parm_name='idle_deconnexion';
            update dms_parametres set parm_value='" . $max_pages_nbr . "' where  parm_name='max_pages_nbr';

    ";

    if (!$parametres->connect()->multi_query($sql)) {
        echo $parametres->connect()->error;
    } else {
        echo 'sucsess';

    }
}
?>
```